# Mac OS 10.4 asking for admin credentials for folder deletion

Tags: mac-osx, optical-media

A user in our company uses Mac OS 10.4 on a G5. She has a CD with Illustrator CS3 stuff on it. She copied 2 folders on the desktop and now she needs to delete both. When she tries, she gets a popup asking to enter Administrator Username and Password.

I just don't get why she can't do that since I burned the Illustrator stuff onto a DVD directly from the server. She was able to open, delete, modify everything from the server but from the DVD, she cannot. I did not change any security settings at all.

Does anyone know about that?

Thanks,
David.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? Can you list the POSIX permissions & ACLs for the file/folder on all of the following: server, DVD, and user's Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it inherited the ownership and file permissions from the box it was copied from.  Since her user isn't the owner OS X wants admin privs to delete it.

Open terminal, cd to desktop, ls -ld on the directory.  Who owns the files and what are the permissions?

Comment: I agree with Haggertus.  We have had problems with our users accidentally copying application bundles to their desktop instead of creating a shortcut.  After they do this one of our administrators has to delete the files.